# "Could not find rake-12.3.3 in any of the sources."

Tags: docker, rake, bundler

I tried running these commands:

```
gem uninstall rake
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install
gem install rake --version=12.3.3
```

I also tried adding rake 12.3.3 to the gemfile and running `bundle install`:

```
gem 'rake', '12.3.3'
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

# for postgres
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev

# for nokogiri
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

# for a JS runtime
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV APP_HOME /readpaths
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install

ADD . $APP_HOME
```

I've just noticed something curios: No matter how often I run `gem uninstall rake` (I tried five times) I always get a message saying:

```
Successfully uninstalled rake-12.3.1
```

When I run gem install rake I get:

```
Successfully installed rake-12.3.3
```

Then, when I run gem uninstall rake again, I get again:

```
Successfully uninstalled rake-12.3.1
```

Comment: I'm getting this same issue on Heroku with my Jekyll 4 site.

Comment: I was getting "Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources".  After using apt-get to install rake-12.3.1 and update what was out of date, I now get "Could not find rake-12.3.3 in any of the sources".What a flaky system!  Never had any problem like this in Windows!

Answer (score 0):

If you come to this error because of Heroku/Jekyll, this is how I fixed it:

- Make sure you *only* have this buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
- Make sure your dyno is actually *on*
- Your `Procfile` should have this: `web: jekyll serve --no-watch --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0`
- Make sure your have `PORT` configured in the `config vars` section of your settings

Answer (score -1):

Try rebuilding the docker container.